# Alternative to SMS verification

Tags: sms-verification

My website uses sms verification to validate user's phone number, but I found that a lot of users use virtual numbers to receive SMS.

Is there any thing I can do to prevent users to use virtual numbers? Or is there any alternative to SMS verification?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to prevent the use of virtual numbers?

Comment: We have a referral program. When users refer a friend to join our website, we will give them some reward. Some users want to get more referral reward so they kept creating new accounts using the virtual numbers.

Comment: @Alan I am curious if you found a solution to your problem as we are facing the same issue here..